# python Tkinter change each rectangle in a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change the color of each rectangle in a list to be a different color and draw them all.
But for some reason it either changes all the rectangles to the same color or stay the same.

Here is the code:

```
def draw(newAuto,canves):
    colorMap = {
        "0":"green",
        "1":"blue",
        "2":"red"
    }
    i=0
    for elem in canves.find_withtag("my_tag"):
        canves.itemconfig(elem, fill=colorMap[str(newAuto[i])])
        i+=i
    canves.after(100, canves.update())
```

I am not sure how to debug it since I can't find where the rectangle element is,
any ideas why it's like that? Perhaps the use of update/after is incorrect?

Comment: What is the value of `newAuto`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing `i` properly, it should be `i+=1`. Also you haven't said what `newAuto` is but I guess the line should read `canves.itemconfig(elem, fill=colorMap[str(i)])`. Hope this helps.